# not able to install anything using opam

Tags: ocaml, opam

I installed opam with homebrew on Mac OS X 10.10. But I can't install anything using opam. This is an example error output that get when I try to install ocamlfind:

```
# opam-version 1.2.0
# os           darwin
# command      ./configure -bindir /Users/roger/.opam/system/bin -sitelib /Users/roger/.opam/system/lib -mandir /Users/roger/.opam/system/man -config /Users/roger/.opam/system/lib/findlib.conf -no-topfind
# path         /Users/roger/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5
# compiler     system (4.02.1)
# exit-code    1
# env-file     /Users/roger/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5/ocamlfind-91360-c61e7b.env
# stdout-file  /Users/roger/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5/ocamlfind-91360-c61e7b.out
# stderr-file  /Users/roger/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.5.5/ocamlfind-91360-c61e7b.err
### stdout ###
# ...[truncated]
# Configuration for str written to site-lib-src/str/META
# Configuration for threads written to site-lib-src/threads/META
# Configuration for unix written to site-lib-src/unix/META
# Configuration for stdlib written to site-lib-src/stdlib/META
# Configuration for bigarray written to site-lib-src/bigarray/META
# Configuration for camlp4 written to site-lib-src/camlp4/META
# Configuration for ocamlbuild written to site-lib-src/ocamlbuild/META
# Configuration for compiler-libs written to site-lib-src/compiler-libs/META
# Configuration for bytes written to site-lib-src/bytes/META
# Detecting compiler arguments: FAILED (see the file ocargs.log for details)
### stderr ###
# ./configure: line 547: cd: src: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try with a previous version of opam?

Comment: It's only "anything in opam" because most things depend on ocamlfind.

Comment: maybe you've accidentally used `sudo` when invoking some `opam` command? Anyway, just try to remove the `~/.opam` folder and reinit it. `brew install opam; opam init` should be enough.

Comment: And, not sure that it is relevant, but is your filesystem case-sensitive?

Comment: I removed the .opam folder and reinstalled opam. No success. My filesystem is not case sensitive.

Comment: BTW: I tried it with older spam version. No success. It looks as if the configure scripts is broken on 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install opam
opam init --comp=4.02.1
eval `opam config env`
ocaml
```

Update:

Sometimes brewed opam can fail with `Illegal Instruction`, in that case you need to reinstall opam from sources:

```
brew reinstall --build-from-source opam
```

Also, you need a working toolchain, i.e., compiler, autotools and other developer tools. You can try to install it using `brew`, e.g., `brew install autotools`, etc. Or you can try to install `xcode` toolchain, including apple command line developer tools.

Comment: opam init --comp=4.02.1 gives:  [ERROR!]Cannot guess host type. You must specify one with the -host option.
### stderr ###
# ./configure: line 190: cd: config/auto-aux: No such file or directory
# ./configure: line 222: ../gnu/config.guess: No such file or directory

Comment: BTW: sudo brew install opam is not recommended and just using installing opam gives [1]7481 illegal hardware instruction if i start opam. Installing from source works but then I'm back to my original question.

Comment: That's much more information, than you gave originally! So, your installation lacks some tools, needed for `opam`. You need to install toolchain manually, this is outside of `opam`. Also, I must confess, that I've never used `brew` and prefer `macports`.

Comment: xcode toolchain was installed. brew reinstall --build-from-source opam did work. Maybe I try macport.

Comment: Just uninstalled opam and ocaml. After brew reinstall --build-from-source opam and ocaml work but I still get the same error if I try to install something with opam.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to install mirage, the problem is because the current directory is not in the CDPATH by default on macOS X. The posix /bin/sh will not "cd src" though can "cd ./src". The quick fix is to do the following before running opam (or just put it in your .bash_profile.

`export CDPATH=.
opam install WHATEVER`