# Opam failures on macOS Sierra

Tags: ocaml, homebrew, macos-sierra, opam, ocamlfind

I'm having problems very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908124/not-able-to-install-anything-using-opam).

I have a MacBook Pro on macOS Sierra. I've installed ocaml and opam via brew. (`brew install ocaml`, `brew install opam`) This installed `ocaml 4.03.0`, and it appears to work fine on its own.

I tried to install `oasis` (`opam install oasis`), but the installation failed due to a failure in installing `ocamlfind`:

```
➜  ~ opam install ocamlfind
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install ocamlfind 1.6.2

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
[ocamlfind] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
[ERROR] The compilation of ocamlfind failed at "./configure -bindir /Users/drautb/.opam/system/bin -sitelib /Users/drautb/.opam/system/lib -mandir /Users/drautb/.opam/system/man -config /Users/drautb/.opam/system/lib/findlib.conf -no-custom -no-topfind".
Processing  1/1: [ocamlfind: rm]
#=== ERROR while installing ocamlfind.1.6.2 ===================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           darwin
# command      ./configure -bindir /Users/drautb/.opam/system/bin -sitelib /Users/drautb/.opam/system/lib -mandir /Users/drautb/.opam/system/man -config /Users/drautb/.opam/system/lib/findlib.conf -no-custom -no-topfind
# path         /Users/drautb/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.6.2
# compiler     system (4.03.0)
# exit-code    1
# env-file     /Users/drautb/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.6.2/ocamlfind-41584-6d07ae.env
# stdout-file  /Users/drautb/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.6.2/ocamlfind-41584-6d07ae.out
# stderr-file  /Users/drautb/.opam/system/build/ocamlfind.1.6.2/ocamlfind-41584-6d07ae.err
### stdout ###
# [...]
# Configuration for str written to site-lib-src/str/META
# Configuration for threads written to site-lib-src/threads/META
# Configuration for unix written to site-lib-src/unix/META
# Configuration for stdlib written to site-lib-src/stdlib/META
# Configuration for bigarray written to site-lib-src/bigarray/META
# Configuration for ocamldoc written to site-lib-src/ocamldoc/META
# Configuration for camlp4 written to site-lib-src/camlp4/META
# Configuration for compiler-libs written to site-lib-src/compiler-libs/META
# Configuration for bytes written to site-lib-src/bytes/META
# Detecting compiler arguments: FAILED (see the file ocargs.log for details)
### stderr ###
# ./configure: line 553: cd: src: No such file or directory



=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
The following actions failed
  ∗  install ocamlfind 1.6.2
No changes have been performed
```

I thought it might be related to `ocaml 4.03.0`, so I tried switching to `ocaml 4.02.1`. (`opam switch 4.02.1`) This fails also:

```
➜  ~ opam switch 4.02.1

=-=- Installing compiler 4.02.1 -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
[default.comp] http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-4.02/ocaml-4.02.1.tar.gz downloaded
Now compiling OCaml. This may take a while, please bear with us...
[ERROR] Compiler build failed at "./configure -prefix /Users/drautb/.opam/4.02.1 -with-debug-runtime":
        # opam-version 1.2.2
        # os           darwin
        # command      ./configure -prefix /Users/drautb/.opam/4.02.1 -with-debug-runtime
        # path         /Users/drautb/.opam/4.02.1/build/ocaml
        # exit-code    2
        # env-file     /Users/drautb/.opam/log/log-42620-d2c37b.env
        # stdout-file  /Users/drautb/.opam/log/log-42620-d2c37b.out
        # stderr-file  /Users/drautb/.opam/log/log-42620-d2c37b.err
        ### stdout ###
        # [ERROR!]Cannot guess host type. You must specify one with the -host option.
        ### stderr ###
        # ./configure: line 190: cd: config/auto-aux: No such file or directory
        # ./configure: line 222: ../gnu/config.guess: No such file or directory
```

I've tried reinstalling XCode, I've tried reinstalling ocaml and opam via homebrew with the `--build-from-source` option, (including `rm -rf ~/.opam`) and the errors persist.

Has anyone else had issues like this?

Comment: Please, report this to opam-repository issue-tracker: https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues

Comment: Done, thanks. https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/7593

Comment: Hi, I added a fix to the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908124/not-able-to-install-anything-using-opam